LUKS partition passphrase prompt not appear on boot
I have follow the following tutorial to do encryption/decryption using cryptsetup on my Raspbian Bookworm OS.
https://rr-developer.github.io/LUKS-on-Raspberry-Pi/
When I done encryption I can decrypt it from initramfs shell, however, when I reboot I will be dropped into initramfs shell and not to the Passphrase prompt which it should be.
NOTE: Everything seem to be find in Raspbian Bulleye OS.
I have check all the configuration I done and everything is fine.

I have fixed this issue as of now. Base on the answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/1424144/encrypted-disk-not-available-in-boot-process-after-distro-upgrade here My problem is that i didn't install cryptsetup-initramfs which handle the process of adding cryptsetup into initramfs. So what I do is just install cryptsetup-initramfs
To install it:
sudo apt install cryptsetup-initramfs

then update the initramfs image:
sudo update-initramfs -u -k $(uname -r)

